# How to count the characters from the csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, collections

My CSV have below data

```
['value']
['abcd']
['def abc']
```

I want to count each characters in descending order of value, value is the header in the csv file. I have  wrote one script below. Is there any better script than this?

```
from csv import DictReader
with open("name.csv") as f:
    a1 = [row["value"] for row in DictReader(f)]
#a1
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter()
for line in a1:
    counts.update(list((line)))
    x=dict(counts)
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for w in sorted(x, key=x.get, reverse=True):
  print (w, x[w])
```

Comment: Please share a sample input and expected output.

Comment: name.csv = ['value']
['abcd']
['def abc']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
path = "name.csv"
d_list = defaultdict(int)

with open(path, 'r') as fl:
    for word in fl:
        for ch in word:
            #if word[0] == ch:
               dd[ch] += 1

del d_list['\n']
del d_list[' ']
#print (d_list)

dd = sorted(d_list.items(), key=lambda v:v[1], reverse=True)
#dd_lex = sorted(dd, key = lambda k: (-k[1],k[0]))

for el in dd:
    print (el[0] + ' '+ str(el[1]))
```